# Defining the type while passing a function through an argument in Python

Tags: python, function, types, arguments

I know there is a way to specify the type of argument like this:

```
def f(x: int)
    return x
```

but what if I want to pass a function as an argument?
For example:

```
class Sth:
    def __init__(self, x: int, f: XXX):
        self.__x = x
        self.__f = f

def a():
    return True


obj = Sth(2, a)
```

What do I type in the place of XXX for it to work?

When I do `type(a)` it shows `<class 'function'>`, but I can not put 'function' in place of XXX

Answer (score 0):

You type 'Callable'. See [reference.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable)

```
from typing import Callable

def __init__(self, x: int, f: Callable):
    pass
```